# Rebuild JSON after $http.get with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, highcharts, splunk

**Update**

Following link provide a working demo with Highchart-ng and the JSON rebuild solution. If you try to use JSON data from Splunk in highchart, this will save your day :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl47Hz5Cnj1jvUT3DTBt?p=preview

--

I am trying to get a JSON response from Splunk to fit into highchart, but im having real problems formating the data right.

I`m a really big fan of AngularJS, but I have some trubble wrapping my head around it, and hope some bright minds can help me.

I have been trying with loops to build the data, but with no luck.
If you cant provide the whole solution, could someone please point me in the correct direction ? :)

Original data from $http.get:

```
[
    {
        "Time": "2015-03-20 20:45:00",
        "Output": {
            "80": 34,
            "443": 234,
            "993": 311,
            "8080": 434
        }
    },
    {
        "Time": "2015-03-20 20:40:00",
        "Output": {
            "80": 0,
            "443": 204,
            "993": 38,
            "8080": 546
        }
    },
    {
        "Time": "2015-03-20 20:35:00",
        "Output": {
            "80": 0,
            "443": 0,
            "993": 90,
            "8080": 10
        }
    }
]
```

What i need the data to look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "80",
        "data": [34, 0, 0]
    },
    {
        "name": "443",
        "data": [234, 204, 0]
    },
    {
        "name": "993",
        "data": [311, 38, 90]
    },
    {
        "name": "8080",
        "data": [434, 546, 10]
    }
]
```

The script i keep coming back to without any luck:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Javascripts -->
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/master/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<script>

var appname = angular.module('appname', ["highcharts-ng"]);

appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope,$http) 
  {

        $http.get("example1.json")
          .success(function(data) {
            process(data);
        });

        function process(data)
        {
        }
    $scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: []
    },{
        data: []
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },

    loading: false
}

  }
]);

</script>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div ng-app="appname" ng-controller="appCtrl">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>        
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.content -->
</div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a correlation between the original data and your desired output.

Comment: Mike: Each value of the "output" is concat with the next, so 80 that is present in 3 outputs, will create [34, 0, 0]

Comment: Gotcha... See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = [
  {
    "Time": "2015-03-20 20:45:00",
    "Output": {
      "80": 34,
      "443": 234,
      "993": 311,
      "8080": 434
    }
  },
  {
    "Time": "2015-03-20 20:40:00",
    "Output": {
      "80": 0,
      "443": 204,
      "993": 38,
      "8080": 546
    }
  },
  {
    "Time": "2015-03-20 20:35:00",
    "Output": {
      "80": 0,
      "443": 0,
      "993": 90,
      "8080": 10
    }
  }
];


function process(data) {
  var arrOutputKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[0].Output),
    outputArray = [];

  arrOutputKeys.forEach(function (keyname) {
    var propData = this.map(function (val) {
      return val.Output[keyname];
    }, keyname);
    outputArray.push({"name": keyname, "data": propData});
  }, data);

  return outputArray;
}

console.log(process(data));
```

Comment: You will have to integrate the return value into the appropriate $scope variable.

Comment: This solution was correct. You saved me from alot of frustration. To all Splunk users out there wanting to parse their data for HighChart, this function will work (with some tweeking to match the object names ofc).

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure the data retrieved view the $http service using the [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) operations to aggregate the results into your desired structure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction Mark, but my Javascript/AngularJS skills does not reach into this advanced programing. :/ I`ll still have a look and see what i can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain Javascript (ES5) solution that makes use of `forEach` and `Object.keys` therefore it will fail in IE8 and less if you don't have a *polyfill*.

```
var result = {};
data.forEach(function(item) {
   Object.keys(item.Output).forEach(function(port) {
       result[port] = result[port] || [];
       result[port].push(item.Output[port]);
   });
});
```

At this step `result` contains a *map* that, provided your data, looks like that :

```
{
    '80': [34, 0, 0], 
    '443': [234, 204, 0], 
    '993': [311, 38, 90], 
    '8080': [434, 546, 10]
}
```

If you want to have in your data model an array of `{name: '...', data: [...]}` objects, here is a complementary step :

```
var finalArray = [];
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(port) {
    finalArray.push({name: port, data: result[port]});
});
```

***Final array :***

```
[{
    'name': '80',
    'data': [34, 0, 0]
}, {
    'name': '443',
    'data': [234, 204, 0]
}, {
    'name': '993',
    'data': [311, 38, 90]
}, {
    'name': '8080',
    'data': [434, 546, 10]
}];
```